# why change DOM property in anonymous function not working?

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function start(){
                document.getElementById("first_div").onclick = function(){
                    document.getElementById("another_div").style.color = "red";                 
                };
            }
        </script>   
    </head>
    <body onload="start()">
        <div id="first_div">first</div>
        <div id="anoter_div">second</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

when I click on the first_div, an error occurred:

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'document.getElementById("another_div")' [null] is not an object.
```

Any idea why this is not working?

thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've made a typo. Change:

```
document.getElementById("another_div")
                             ^
```

To:

```
document.getElementById("anoter_div")
```

Or you could change the name of your `div`, which is probably better:

```
<div id="anoter_div">second</div>

<div id="another_div">second</div>
             ^
```

The method `document.getElementById(..)` isn't able to find the element and returns null, which explains the error you're getting.